# How should I solve the problem 'The PDF of $X$ is $f(x)$, what is the PDF of $g(X)$?'

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

By example I would like to understand how to solve problems of this kind: 'The probability density function (PDF) of $X$ is $f(x)$, what is the PDF of $g(X)$?'

For example, if $X$ has PDF $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, what is the PDF of $Y:=\log(X)$? The solution is $h(y)=e^{y-\alpha-\exp(y-\alpha)}$ with $\alpha=-\log(\lambda)$.

Comment: A pretty standard (and somewhat general, but possibly overkill, as pointed out by Arthur) technique is to compute $E(\phi(Y))$ for any continuous bounded $\phi$. If you find something of the form $E(\phi(Y)) = \int \phi(y) h(y) dy$, then $h$ is the PDF of $Y$.

Comment: Transforming PDFs is tricky to get right. Transforming CDFs is a lot easier to do correctly. I'd go with that option whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I figured it out. What is needed is a change of variable.

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)|$$

In the example $g(y)=\log(y)$, so

$$f_X(g^{-1}(y)) = \lambda e^{-\lambda \exp(y)}$$

and

$$|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)|=e^y$$

The solution follows directly from this.

Comment: For the sake of generality and in case it would be useful to anybody else reading this: There are at least three different approaches to solving this kind of problem, which are each suitable for different situations (such as when the above does not work). There are (1) the method of distribution functions (https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/156/), (2) the method of transformations (https://academic.csuohio.edu/bmargolius/homepage/courses/mth424/notes/transf.pdf), and (3) the method of moment-generating functions (https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/131/).

Comment: @JackCrawford Isn't (2) equal to the method above?

Comment: yeah, I just wanted to list them inclusively. I should probably also add that there's a general version using the Jacobian for multivariate situations. (https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec1-5.pdf)

Comment: It gets a little more complicated if $g^{-1}(y)$ does not exist as a function, for example when $g(x)$ is not 1-1 injective